# Skipping element in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Would you please help me in this problem? I have an array like this

```
a = [1,2,3,0,0,0,3,4,5]
```

and I want the output to be

```
a = [1,2,3,0,0,0,4,5,6]
```

or `a = [1,2,3,0,3,4,5] -> a = [1,2,3,0,4,5,6]`

So, I know how to detect duplicate and increase number in the list. But my problem is how can I detect 0 and "skip" it in my iteration through the list? Any help is appreciated (Python 2.7 is ideal since we use 2.7)

my way so far is

```
i = 1
while i < len(a): 
    if a[i-1] == a[i]:
        a[i] = a[i]+1
 i = i+1
```

and, obviously it only works if `a = [1,2,3,3,4,5]`

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information on the algorithm, do you increment based on the `0`, e.g. does `[1,2,0,3,4]` become `[1,2,0,4,5]` or does it increment because of the duplicate `3` (ignoring `0`s), e.g. `[1,2,3,3,4]` becomes `[1,2,3,4,5]`. And you haven't showed any attempt on your part.

Comment: no, it's enough. Since, I only have the cases [1,2,3,0,4,5] or [1,2,3,0,0,4,5]. And, it will be "always" like that in my environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- define an auxiliary set to test if element has already been used
- special case: if 0, pass-through
- scan the original list, and increase by 1 until not in aux set
- add the new value to the set
- append to output list

(No list comprehension here since there's a side-effect)

my proposal:

```
a = [1,2,3,0,0,0,3,4,5]
b = []
s = set()

for i in a:
    if i:
        while i in s:
            i+=1
        s.add(i)
    b.append(i)
```

Note: depending on the data, the `set` may be overkill. If you only have data parts increasing (except for the zero) 1 memory slot should be enough:

```
a = [1,2,3,0,0,0,3,4,5]
b = []

highest = 0
for i in a:
    if i!=0:
        if i <= highest:
            i=highest+1
        highest = i
    b.append(i)
```

(which is faster because it doesn't increase `i`, just takes the highest value + 1)

Comment: it works. I was using iteration through the list and comparing a[i-1] and a[i], then set a[i]=a[i]+1. That way only detects duplicate but not skipping 0. Thank you for the help.

Comment: if the list parts are sorted in increasing order except for zeroes, you could make it simpler by memorizing the last non-zero element (no need for a `set`)